# Flutter : document firestore api

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Fuo.png)

I There's a document issue here, it looks simple but I'm just learning it. and would like to know its problem

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

The property is called `docs`, not `documents`. So:

```
snapshot.docs.forEach(...)
```

Also see the documentation for the [`QuerySnapshot` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html)